# Is there a way to execute for loop logic across multiple pods?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I was using NestJs and Kubernetes and had a function in my service which has a for loop similar to below.
This takes quite a while to pull data as it runs on the same pod. Was wondering if there a way to convert this function into an individual calls to each country which will run on different pods

**countries.controller.ts**

```
@Get()
async fetchData() {

  return await this.fetchData();

}
```

**countries.service.ts**

```
async fetchData() {

  for(const country of countries) {

   await this.getNewsFeed(country);

  }

}
```